# How to search on a field that may be empty in zapier

Tags: postgresql, zapier, airtable

Trying to sync up a postgres record to airtable on create/update. The field has a couple of ids that I would like to check for in airtable to determine whether I should create a new record or update an existing one. The first id (optional_id) I need to search on can possibly be null. This causes the search to fail before it can get to the other id(required_id) that should always be populated. Is there any way I can skip the initial search for optional_id if it turns out to be null in postgres?

My current outline is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Formatter > Text > Default Value step in case the input value can be *null* and then make sure the fallback value is from a record that does not exist.

If further help is needed, feel free to reach out to us here:

https://zapier.com/app/get-help